# Donwloading multiple online powerpoint presentations

Tags: excel

I intend to download multiple online powerpoint files (around 500) for doing that I am using this vba code , although it works for pdf , jpg and other formats. The powerpoint files being downloaded are all wrong having a size of 16kb each.

Is there any alternative method to do this ? It will be a great help

```
Sub download_multple_photos()

dlpath = "C:\DownloadedPics\"

For i = 2 To 7
    imgsrc = Cells(i, 2)
    imgname = Cells(i, 1)
    URLDownloadToFile 0, imgsrc, dlpath & imgname & ".pptx", 0, 0
`
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: If you open that URL directly from a web browser does it download the PowerPoint file properly?  It seems like the URL you're feeding it is incorrect or they're served up differently than the other files you're downloading.  Have you checked the actual contents returned?

Comment: Hey Yeah when I open the url as it's an online presentation you cannot click control + S to save it or even right click doesn't work. But at the top right corner there is an option where you can click and download the presentation easily

Comment: Do you have an example link to one of the pptx files you're having issues with?  I assume it has something to do with how the files are served but I can't gather much info without something to check against.